What is the importance of philosophy in the development of scientific and abstract thinking?
Is there evidence for this? In which books or articles could I find more information?
I've been researching, and it seems that logic and epistemology are relevant for developing scientific thinking, but I'm still not entirely sure if that's all there is to it. As for the development of abstract thinking, I've been digging quite a bit, but I haven't found as much information as I expected. Or maybe I just don't know how to search properly... Philosophy isn't my field, so I know little to nothing about it. I'd really appreciate it if someone could guide me a bit on this.

As you can imagine from the tags "philosophy of..." you have used, phil is relevant wrt the foundations and the grounding concepts of scientific practices.

In mathematics (since 19th century) philosophy has been tremendously important - but allmost all actual relevant contributions came from mathematicians: Frege, Russell, Pierce, Brouwer. One very good source is Jean van Heijenoort, From Frege to Godel: A Source Book in Mathematical Logic, 1879-1931 (Source Books in History of Sciences) (2002).
Intellectual development in general has been driven by scientists (engineers and artists), not by philosophers. (All creative new, useful ideas about language the last half century have come from computational (and cognitive) scientists imo.)

Can you clarify: are you asking about the historical development of scientific thinking (history of science), or an individual person developing scientific thinking skills (pedagogy of science)?

I elaborated on this in my answer here: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/100740/which-field-is-more-rigorous-mathematics-or-philosophy/100810#100810

The most effective method to develop scientific thinking is doing scientific research yourself, hands-on. For science, one always needs the capability of abstract thinking, e.g., the method of generalization. By doing math this method can be learned and the results can be checked.
Philosophy seems to me the second best method to develop scientific and abstract thinking. Nevertheless it is always good for science to reflect and assess the great ideas from the history of philosophy. To read the classics on ontology, epistemology, logic – if only to recognize which of their ideas are outdated ...

Lecture List - Galileo and Einstein:
https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/109N/lectures/lecturelist.html
Galileo probably did more than any other figure of history to incorporate philosophy into the modern scientific paradigm. He used both logical arguments and mathematical models to invalidate, or falsify, certain statements of Aristotle concerning the motion of falling bodies, speed of motion, etc. He argued that the earth orbits the Sun based on a mix of experimental observations and logical arguments. Kepler understood that data for planetary forward and retrograde motion could fit into a Ptolemaic model with epicycles but the same data could also fit into or transform to another model for eliptical orbits without the use of epicycles. It seems the best scientists are applied philosophers who try to fit concepts with perceptions into better or more coherent models in some perceptive context.
Karl Popper refers to a hypothesis that can be falsified as a falsifiable hypothesis:
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/popper/
Psychoanalysis did not contain any falsifiable or predictive hypothesis according to Popper. The idea that science is or should be limited to testing falsifiable statements has been criticized by many philosophers.

These factors combined to make Popper take falsifiability as his criterion for demarcating science from non-science: if a theory is incompatible with possible empirical observations it is scientific; conversely, a theory which is compatible with all such observations, either because, as in the case of Marxism, it has been modified solely to accommodate such observations, or because, as in the case of psychoanalytic theories, it is consistent with all possible observations, is unscientific. However, Popper is not a positivist and acknowledges that unscientific theories may be enlightening and that even purely mythogenic explanations have performed a valuable function in the past in expediting our understanding of the nature of reality.


For Popper the central problem in the philosophy of science is that of demarcation, i.e., of distinguishing between science and what he terms “non-science” (e.g., logic, metaphysics, psychoanalysis, and Adler’s individual psychology). Popper is unusual amongst contemporary philosophers in that he accepts the validity of the Humean critique of induction, and indeed, goes beyond it in arguing that induction is never actually used in science. However, he does not concede that this entails scepticism and argues that the Baconian/Newtonian insistence on the primacy of “pure” observation, as the initial step in the formation of theories, is completely misguided: all observation is selective and theory-laden and there are no pure or theory-free observations. In this way he destabilises the traditional view that science can be distinguished from non-science on the basis of its inductive methodology. In contradistinction to this, Popper holds that there is no unique methodology specific to science; rather, science, like virtually every other organic activity, consists largely of problem-solving.

